# Pandas: difference between frame.loc[:, 'col'] and frame['col']

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to pandas, and I am refactoring some code that seems verbose. However, I have found a lot the following selection:

```
frame.loc[:, 'col']
```

So, my question is if this is equivalent to:

```
frame['col']
```

because I would like to use the latter form since the former seems verbose. However, if there is any difference please let me know, and talking about performance, is one better than the other?

Comment: Depends on whether you're going to assign to it, it may work on the second version but the first is implicitly working on a view. If you're just selecting columns, then they're equivalent

Comment: @EdChum, well on most computations I see it selects columns this way, and perform computations such as `return frame.loc[:, 'col1'] + frame.loc[:, 'col2']`, so is it okay to change it to `return frame['col1] +  frame['col2']`?

Comment: Yes but context is important, `loc` here is attempting to return a view, if you assign to this, then it will try to raise a warning, the latter may not but it depends on context

Comment: @EdChum, thank you, and one more question. Is there any difference about performance, or not difference at all between them?

Comment: Should be no difference, if performance is an issue then look at the docs for iat etc. Would post a link but I'm on my mobile

Comment: @EdChum, thank you so much for your help and time. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question the context matters.

The first one:

```
frame.loc[:, 'col']
```

implicitly selects all rows, and the 'col' of interest and returns a view, the implicit use case here is for assignment.

The other method:

```
frame['col']
```

Returns the 'col' of interest but assignment to this may or may not work.

If the intention is just to return the 'col' of interest then they are both the same, but if you intend to assign to this then the first method is returning a view so the original df will be affected.

Regarding your comment about performance, there is probably no difference between the two but for fast access you should look at [`at` or `iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#fast-scalar-value-getting-and-setting) for fast scalar access.

Additionally the other semantic difference is [assignment with enlargment](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#setting-with-enlargement), this is intended for either appending a row that doesn't exist, or adding a column.

Comment: fantastic answer, thank you. Could you please give me a context in which `frame['col']` might not work?

Comment: it's more to do with if you filter a df e.g. `var = frame['col']` and then `var = 0` this may or may not work, it may or may not raise a warning: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#why-does-assignment-fail-when-using-chained-indexing whilst `loc` should work but may not but it should raise a warning